# Simple path in a Finite Acceptor

Tags: automata, finite-automata

What is the definition of a 'simple path' in a finite acceptor?
My concern is whether self loops can be considered as a part of simple path from initial to final state?

Answer (score 2):

The only reasonable definition for a simple path in a finite acceptor would be a finite path in its transition graph, i.e. no vertices (states) may appear twice in that path. This especially excludes paths that use self loops.

Comment: That means if there is no simple path from initial state to final state then language accepted will be empty. Right?

Comment: Yes, the language is empty if every finite state in unreachable from the initial state, in this case there is especially no simple path.